# Error when loading knowrob: java does not exist

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,
I have some errors when loading the knowrob like this message
"**ERROR: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:22:
'$open_shared_object'/3: libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:22:
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/knowrob/3rdparty/jpl/prolog/jpl.pl:4643: Initialization goal raised exception:
**library** `java' does not exist (Please add directory holding libjava.so to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
ERROR: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:23:
jpl:jpl_set_default_jvm_opts/1: Undefined procedure: jpl:jni_set_default_jvm_opts/2
Warning: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:23:
Goal (directive) failed: user:jpl_set_default_jvm_opts([-Xmx256M])"**
Please if you can help me to solve these errors.
Thanks
Ahmed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11416/error-when-loading-knowrob:-java-does-not-exist/) by [ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/1156/ahmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

have you installed all system dependencies? (execute the apt-get command generated by 'rosdep satisfy knowrob'). It sounds like Java is not correctly installed on your system. After this, try a 'rosmake --pre-clean knowrob'

If that does not help, some information about your setup would help (Java JDK type and version, OS version, which command produces this error etc).

thanks,
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3